# Refactoring this jQuery code

Tags: jquery, scroll

```
$('.go2page1').click(function() {
  $("body").scrollTo({
    top: '0px',
    left: '0px'
  }, 800);
  return false;
});
$('.go2page2').click(function() {
  $("body").scrollTo({
    top: '0px',
    left: '1100px'
  }, 800);
  return false;
});
$('.go2page3').click(function() {
  $("body").scrollTo({
    top: '0px',
    left: '2200px'
  }, 800);
  return false;
});
$('.go2page4').click(function() {
  $("body").scrollTo({
    top: '0px',
    left: '3300px'
  }, 800);
  return false;
});
```

This works but there are several pages and I have one for each, possible to compress this into a few lines and also add 'active' to the selected page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.go2page').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').scrollTo({
        top: $(this).data('top'),
        left: $(this).data('left')
    }, 800);
});
```

Then make all your links `class="go2page" data-left="3300px" data-top="0px"` (of course replace the offsets with the correct ones).

While `data-` attributes are a HTML5 thing, no browsers have problems with unknown attributes so the code works fine in all browsers. HTML validators will complain though unless you use the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: data-offset="3300px" only has one value, but I need to provide two?

Comment: @Nimbuz well then use "data-top" and "data-left" maybe?

Comment: @Nimbuz In ThiefMaster's example, he used just "data-offset", which you would code as an attribute on your "go2page" elements (whatever they are).  What I'm suggesting is that you'd have *two* attributes, "data-top" and "data-left".  The code would use the jQuery ".data()" method, as in ThiefMaster's example, but it would fetch the "top" value *and* the "left" value, instead of just the single "offset". The [jQuery ".data()" documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) explains how it works with "data-foo" attributes.

Comment: @Nimbuz: I've updated my answer. Even though it should have been easy for your to do it on your own with some basic knowledge. ;)

Answer (score 1):

rather than storing the data for offset in the link I think I'd try an approach to get the offset from the "page" element (with + or - modifiers to center on that element)

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/jDFJw/

jQuery:

```
$('.pageLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the page div element
    var $page = $($(this).attr("href"));

    // ScrollTo using the div's offset properties
    $('body').scrollTo({ 
        top: ($page.offset().top - 20) + "px", // scroll 20px above the page element
        left: ($page.offset().left) + "px" 
    }, 800);

    // Set .selected class
    $('.pageLink').removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="#page1" class="pageLink selected">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#page2" class="pageLink">Page 2</a>
    <a href="#page3" class="pageLink">Page 3</a>
    <a href="#page4" class="pageLink">Page 4</a>
</div>

<div id="page1" class="page">Page 1</div>
<div id="page2" class="page">Page 2</div>
<div id="page3" class="page">Page 3</div>
<div id="page4" class="page">Page 4</div>
```

Comment: divs are positioned absolutely.

Comment: absolute positioned elements still have offset left/top values